# Re-implementing lists with closures in scheme

Tags: list, scheme, closures

This is purely a curiosity question for me:

So for fun, one can easily redefine cons, car, and cdr like so:

```
(define cons+
  (lambda (a b)
    (lambda (f)
      (f a b)
  )))

(define car+
  (lambda (f)
    (f (lambda (a b) a))))

(define cdr+
  (lambda (f)
    (f (lambda (a b) b))))
```

This creates the basic functionality of a list using closures. In this context, what would be the best way to define an empty list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no *particular* special value that you need as the empty list;  you just need something and then to treat it as the empty list.  In Common Lisp, a list is either a cons or the symbol NIL.  You could take the same approach and use the symbol NIL, or you could use some other value, so long as you treat it consistently.  Part of the beauty (and sometimes, the ugliness) of linked lists in the Lisp families is that they are *intensional data structures*.  They're built out of a bit of structure and a lot of convention.  That's why we can use cons cells to implement singly-linked lists, tree, etc.

Now, what does it mean to treat it consistently?  Some of that will depend on exactly how you want it to behave.  In Common Lisp, you can call **car** and **cdr** with the empty list, and you'll get back the empty list.  In Scheme, you'll get an error.  In the closure-based approach, you've got a "leaky" abstraction in the sense that you can call **car+** and **cdr+** with values that were not produced by **cons+**, and you *might* get a value back.

### What interface do you want?

When implementing singly linked lists in the Lisp styles (conses and an empty list), you typically want an interface that will let you check:

```
(cons? (cons ...)) == true
(empty? empty)     == true
```

(In terms of those, you can implement **list?**)

```
(define (list? x)
  (or (cons? x)
      (null? x)))
```

After what you've already done, it shouldn't be hard to implement a **cons?** function.  But what about **empty?**?  You actually have a lot of freedom here.  You could implement **empty?** such that there are actually multiple objects that serve as a empty lists.  As long as the contract works, it's OK.

### Should anything else work?

At the moment, you've got a working implementation of ordered pairs, but it's a [leaky abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) in that some things that weren't created with **cons** could still be passed to **car** and **cdr** without any error.  You've satisfied the axioms

```
(car (cons x y)) == x
(cdr (cons x y)) == y
```

but not the implications

> `(car z) == x`     ⇒     `z == (cons x _)`
>   `(cdr z) == y`     ⇒     `z == (cons _ y)`

If you can find a way to make those implications true, so that **car** and **cdr** only work with things produced by **cons**, then you can probably figure out how to implement **cons?**, and you can use the same technique to generate a unique empty list object.

Comment: Isn't your definition of `list?` a tad short?

Comment: @Sylwester I'm not sure exactly what you mean, unless you're commenting about the difference between a **list?** and **proper-list?**.  I was following Common Lisp tradition where [listp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_listp.htm) checks whether something is a cons or the empty list, "listp does not check whether object is a proper list; it returns true for any kind of list."  The Scheme **list?** might check for proper lists.