# Defining cons, car and cdr with lambda - how does it work?

Tags: lambda, scheme, sicp, r5rs

I can't seem to explain how this definition of cons, car and cdr works:

```
(define (p-cons x y)
   (lambda (proc) (proc x y)))

(define (p-car proc)
   (proc (lambda (p q) p)))

(define (p-cdr proc)
   (proc (lambda (p q) q)))
```

I understand that the first procedure returns a procedure which takes a procedure as an argument, and applies this procedure to the two arguments x y. What I don't understand is how car and cdr works:

```
(p-car (p-cons "foo" "bar")) -> foo
(p-cdr (p-cons "foo "bar")) -> bar
```

If someone could explain how this works I would appreciate it! How does the lambda-expression in 'car' and 'cdr' get the 'p' and 'q' variables for exemple?

Comment: I think this has been descibed in another answer

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [Use of lambda for cons/car/cdr definition in SICP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21769348/1281433).

Comment: Or of [Re-implementing lists with closures in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27111724/1281433)

Comment: I think that the first of those linked duplicates is probably the most useful for you.

Comment: use better, more suggestive names, like `(define (p-cons x y) (lambda (sel) (sel x y)))`. Now it is plain that `(p-cons x y)` creates a procedure that expects a selector procedure, and passes it the two arguments that were given to `p-cons`. Then `car` just supplies the selector of the  1st argument, and `p-cdr` - of the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a substitution:

```
(p-car (p-cons "foo" "bar"))

;substituting p-cons:
(p-car (lambda (proc) (proc "foo" "bar")))

;substituting p-car:
((lambda (proc) (proc "foo" "bar")) (lambda (p q) p))

((lambda (p q) p) "foo" "bar")

"foo"
```

And similarly for `p-cdr`.

Essentially `p-cons` just creates a lambda which expects a procedure which will pick the appropriate stored value. `p-car` picks the first, `p-cdr` the second.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I haven't thought of using the substitution model before, I have spent a really long time trying to understand this.